# Taxonomy Tags Comments

Tags: taxonomy-terms, comments

I am having a problem removing the comments link from a page.
I am using Taxonomy and Tags, I added a term to Tags and gave it a URL alias such as tags/sandy_repair.
I created a new basic page and added that term to the page.
When you display the page it lists that tag at the bottom.
When you click on the tag link it takes you to the alias you created that would display the teasers of all the

pages with the same tags. So the tag links to tags/sandy_repair
On this page there is a comment icon and a link to 0 comments ()
I would like to remove that icon and comments link entirely.
The structure of the Basic page is not set to display comments, manage display does not even show comments and the

Comment Display tab has the comment field hidden.
The only thing I can figure is that this comment display is not coming from the basic page settings.

Answer (score 0):

What theme do you use? 
Have your tried unsetting the comment links in your node template using something along `unset($content['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-add']);`?